# Does anyone know why Core Animation FPS in Xcode9.3 instruments does not have "debug options"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Does anyone know why Core Animation FPS in Xcode9.3 instruments does not have "debug options"? And why does iOS 8 crash when recording in instruments?